# How to code for the "." for the Use of decimal input?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, calculator

I am developing the calculator for android.
I have implemented all the functionality, Now just getting stop at the decimal value.
I dont know how to implement that functionality on the click of custom "." button.
I want decimal value up to two fraction point.
can anybudy help me to develop such code?
I need it. . . I know it seem very easy but right now i got stuck in that matter.
Pleae help me in this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact problem you have? You cannot convert "12.34" to double or what?

Comment: Actualy i want code to implement the "." button as operate in normale calculator. But the different is I want to implement it for only two decimal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, this is a very broad question. I recommend you to check this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androidcalculator.aspx

Generally speaking, you need to:
1) Implement UI
2) Implement click handlers for the buttons
3) Implement evaluation function

If you get stuck at something particular ask it here and post your code.

***EDIT:***
There you can see how it is implemented, you can use similar logic:

```
    case DECIMAL_SEP: // Handle decimal seperator
        if (hasFinalResult || resetInput) { // if previous result is calculated or the input is reset, insert 0 before
            userInputText.setText("0.");
            hasFinalResult = false;
            resetInput = false;
        } else if (currentInput.contains(".")) // don't let 2nd '.'
            return;
        else
            userInputText.append("."); // append '.'
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks, Las_VEGAS: I have implement all the functionality for it. But just now to remain the implementation of the decimal point value.